# Soma de fatoriais em um range especifico

Tags: python

Preciso somar os fatoriais de 1 a 10, mas n encontrei o melhor jeito de implementar essa função.

```
def soma_fatorial():
    resultado = 1
    for i in range(1, 11):
        resultado = resultado * i
    return resultado
```

Answer (score 6):

O fatorial de um número `n`, por [definição](https://www.todamateria.com.br/fatorial/) é *o produto de todos os números começando por `n` até `1`.*

Pois bem, para calcular o fatorial de um número podemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def fatorial(n):
    prod = 1
    for c in range(n, 0, -1):
        prod *= c
    return prod


num = int(input('Digite um número inteiro: '))

print(fatorial(num))
```

---

Agora, pelo que entendi do seu enunciado você deseja calcular a soma de todos os fatoriais de `1` até `n`.

**1ª Forma de resolver:**

Para calcularmos esta soma devemos utilizar o seguinte código:

```
def soma_fatorial(n):
    soma = 0
    for c in range(1, n + 1):
        prod = 1
        for d in range(c, 0, -1):
            prod *= d
        soma += prod
    return soma


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(soma_fatorial(num))
```

Observe neste segundo código que o **primeiro for** da função `soma_fatorial` percorre o range dos números que desejamos calcular o respectivo fatorial e o **último for** calcula o fatorial da respectiva iteração.

**Vamos testar o código:**

**Exemplo 1**

Calcule a soma dos fatoriais de **1** até **3**

Neste caso, executamos o código e quando recebemos a mensagem; `Digite um número`, Devemos digitar o limite superior, que neste caso é **3**. Em seguida recebermos a seguinte saída:

```
9
```

Pois **9 = 1! + 2! + 3! = 1 + 2 + 6 = 9**

**Exemplo 2**

Calcule a soma dos fatoriais de **1** até **10**

Neste caso, executamos o código e quando recebemos a mensagem; `Digite um número`, Devemos digitar o limite superior, que neste caso é **10**. Em seguida recebermos a seguinte saída:

```
4037913
```

Pois **4037913 = 1! + 2! + 3! + 4! + 5! + 6! + 7! + 8! + 9! + 10! = 4037913**

---

**2ª Forma de resolver:**

Outra forma interessante de resolver esta questão é utilizando o método **factorial** da biblioteca **math**. Dessa forma, a solução seria:

```
from math import factorial


def soma_fatorial(n):
    soma = 0
    for c in range(1, n + 1):
        soma += factorial(c)
    return soma


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(soma_fatorial(num))
```

---

**3ª Forma de resolver:**

Também pode-se resolver esta questão por **compreensão de lista**. Neste caso, a resolução seria:

```
from math import factorial


def soma_fatorial(n):
    return sum([factorial(c) for c in range(1, n + 1)])


num = int(input('Digite um número: '))

print(soma_fatorial(num))
```

---

**4ª Forma de resolver:**

Outra coisa, você pode resolver esta questão **sem** utilizar **funções def**. Para isso você utilizaria **apenas 2 linhas de código**. Neste caso a solução seria:

```
from math import factorial

print(sum([factorial(c) for c in range(1, int(input('Digite um número: ')) + 1)]))
```

Answer (score 4):

Fazer um laço que percorre os números de 1 a n calculando o fatorial de cada um separadamente pode não ser uma boa ideia (exceto quando n=51), a menos que tenha implementado alguma camada de [memoization](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/33438/5878), que não foi o caso das outras respostas ([1](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477480/5878) e [2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/477485/5878)).

Sabendo que n! = n*(n-1)!, a soma dos fatoriais fica:

```
S = 1! + 2! + 3! + ... + n!
S = 1! + 2*1! + 3*2*1! + ... + n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*3*2*1!
S = 1! * (1 + 2 + 3*2 + ... + n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*3*2)
S = 1! * (1 + 2 * (1 + 3 * (1 + 4 * (... + (n-1) * (1 + n))))
```

Ou seja, para calcular o fatorial do próximo número basta multiplicá-lo pelo fatorial do número anterior. Para a soma deles, basta acumular todos esses valores em forma de adição.

```
def soma_fatorial(n):
    soma = 0
    fatorial = 1
    for numero in range(1, n+1):
      fatorial = numero * fatorial
      soma += fatorial
    return soma

print(soma_fatorial(10))  # 4037913
```

Com isso você reduz a complexidade do seu algoritmo de O(n²) para O(n).

---

Você ainda pode melhorar a solução com separação das responsabilidades utilizando geradores, como mostrei [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/297602/5878):

```
def fatorial_range(n):
    """ Retorna o fatorial de todos os números entre 1 e n """
    next_value = 1
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        yield next_value
        next_value *= i + 1

print(sum(fatorial_range(10)))  # 4037913
```

Answer (score 3):

Como não percebi nenhum pré-requisito na questão. Acredito que a forma mais direta seria usar os recursos do Python para tal. Neste caso a recursividade.

```
>>> def fatorial(n):
...     if n == 0:
...         return 1
...     return n * fatorial(n - 1)
...
>>> fatorial(0)
1
>>> fatorial(1)
1
>>> fatorial(5)
120
```

Sendo assim, para pegar a soma dos fatoriais de um range específico, bastaria

```
>>> sum([fatorial(s) for s in range(2, 6)])
152
```

Nota: O comando `range` no Python pega do número inicial até um antes do número final. Ou seja, no exemplo acima de 2 até 5

```
fatorial de 2 = 2
fatorial de 3 = 6
fatorial de 4 = 24
fatorial de 5 = 120
```

A soma de todos 152

**Update**: Esta forma permite que você some fatoriais de números não sequenciais. No exemplo abaixo a soma dos fatoriais de 2, 3, 5 e 8.

```
>>> sum([fatorial(s) for s in [2, 3, 5, 8]])
40448
```

Espero ter ajudaddo.